# NodeMailer keeps timing out

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, gmail, nodemailer

I'm building my first node project and I'm trying to send mails to users using nodemailer and OAuth2.0. It did work last night but suddenly started timing out this morning no matter what, it runs for a few minutes and then times out without sending the mail.
This is my code so far

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const sendEmail = async (email, subject, text) => {
    try {
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                type: 'OAuth2',
                user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
                pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
                clientId: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENTID,
                clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
                refreshToken: process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN
            }
        });

        await transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'user@gmail.com',
            to: email,
            subject: subject,
            text: text,
        });

        console.log("email sent sucessfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, "email not sent");
    }
};
```

and I'm calling the function this way `await sendEmail(email, "Password reset", link)`
I get this error message after a few minutes

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 173.194.76.108:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
  errno: -60,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '173.194.76.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
} email not sent
```

I would appreciate any help as I'm really frustrated already

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding this to the transporter object

```
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 587,
secure: false,
```